# Is Scarlet Witch more powerful than Doctor Strange?

Tags: marvel, comics, doctor-strange

[X-Men Wikia](http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Scarlet_Witch) says that:

> Wanda is the most powerful mutant, with Jean Grey (White Phoenix) right behind her. Wanda possessed incredible power of Chaos Magic. Wanda's power can warp reality and existence and bring total destruction of cosmos. According to S.H.I E.L.D, Wanda's Comparative Mutagenic Power is 9.3. Wanda is also a class 5 mutant as stated by Iron Man and an Omega level mutant.

Talking about Doctor Strange, he isn't a mutant, but he also possesses magical abilities. He is a master of the Mystic Arts. Can he counter Chaos Magic? Has such an encounter ever happened in comics?

Comment: https://www.superherodb.com/battle/doctor-strange-vs-scarlet-witch/40-1140/

Comment: “Wanda is the most powerful mutant, with Jean Grey (White Phoenix) right behind her.” Perhaps more importantly, is Wanda still this powerful when Jean Grey *isn’t* right behind her?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Haha.. Yeah, you interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Arguably, Strange has certain “pull” that Wanda doesn’t have since he is Sorcerer Supreme (at least he was last time I checked). So he may be able to do more but chooses not to.

Answer (score 7):

The Scarlet Witch's hex power (which alters probability/reality) is a mutant power. At one point, she was taught some magic by Agatha Harkness, the FF's old nanny, but magic was never her main power.

Wanda transformed the entire world in "House of M". Stephen Strange has never accomplished anything like that on his own (though in Doc Strange vol. 2, #13,  when the Earth is destroyed, he and the Ancient One persuade Eternity to recreate it). So I'd say that Wanda is the most powerful, but not as versatile as Doc Strange, who is the greater magician (as Wanda's main power is a mutant one).

Comment: Note that, traditionally, Dr. Strange does very little "on his own"; most of his spells have historically involved invoking some entity to create some effect. Over the years, some of the various entities have even made appearances (for example, the Crimson Bands of Cytorrak tying to the Gem of Cytorrak that granted Juggernaut his abilities, and then eventually seeing Cytorrak himself). ...

Comment: ... In fact, in the 1990s, Dr. Strange's magic changed form several times because he owed those various entities service in return for his requests for their aid/power. At first they had him try different forms of magic (something elemental at one point), then they finally had him serve the entities for what was (something like) 1000 years to him, but happened off screen between seconds for us. Note that the shifts amongst types of magic basically corresponded to shifts in the book's writer.

Comment: [This](http://marvel.com/universe/Scarlet_Witch_(Wanda_Maximoff)) indicates the Scarlet Witch's power isn't _just_ a mutant ability, that there's actual magic mixed in due to circumstances around her birth.

Comment: Strange has in the past called upon transcendental entities (and not always *nice* entities) to do some big-scale things.  Wanda has done big-scale things apparently on her own, using her intrinsic mutant magic thing.  Strange's (ab)use of otherworldly powers usually comes with consequences later; Wanda apparently doesn't have to pay any extra mystical dues. I'm guessing Wanda is much more powerful if you only count intrinsic abilities.  Strange might be able to do even bigger things than her by selling his soul to Shuma-Gorath or something, but not on his own, & he has to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - While the Scarlet Witch may indeed be able to do more on her own than Dr. Strange, it's unclear that she normally has full access to that level of power. Lately, she's been portrayed as being a powerful witch (over and above her mutant powers), but not necessarily more powerful than Dr. Strange.

The Scarlet Witch's power has changed repeatedly, over the years.

Originally, her "hex power" simply involved the ability to alter probabilities in some random way, usually to her benefit. It generally took a few minutes for her power to "recharge" in the early days.

Over time, she gained better control of her power, sometimes being able to create a specific effect, and being able to cast "hexes" more frequently.

Eventually, she did begin to study magic (as noted in other answers) under Agatha Harkness (circa *Avengers* #128 et seq.). At this point, things begin to be less well-defined; it's not clear at any given moment whether she's using her mutant powers, magic, or some combination of both. It does seem like the combination of magic and mutant power was part of what allowed her to achieve specific effects with a hex.

A few years later, her powers were tied to Wundagore Mountain (where she was born) and to Ch'thon, who seemed to have some access to our dimension there. This increased the fogginess between her mutant abilities and magic, as a form of magic seemed to be tied into her mutant powers.

The nature of her abilities seemed to mostly remain constant for several years. in the late 1990s, they were tied to chaos magic (circa *Avengers* v3, #1-3). However, again, most of the time her powers seemed in line with the long-standing "probability altering mutant power, augmented/controlled by magic". Occasional stories indicated that she continued to study magic.

Her powers peaked in the 2000s, where she subconsciously decimated the Avengers (*Avengers* 500-503); then changed the world so mutants were in charge; then almost completely wiped out mutants (the *House of M* series/storyline); then wandered around not like an amnesiac; finally, undoing her "No more mutants" "spell". All of these events happened after she lost her children and went through the experience of having her husband, the Vision, de- and re-constructed, coming back without an emotional connection to her. In other words, for most of these events, she was not necessarily in her right mind. It's unclear if that state of mind allowed her greater access to her powers, or simply removed inhibitions she would normally have had against using them as she did.

When she regained her senses, she seemed to have difficulty undoing what she had done; reversing the whole "No more mutants" bit required assistance (*Avengers: The Children's Crusade*).

Her recent solo series (circa 2015-2016) established her as a member of the magickal community in good standing, and seems to indicate her magic abilities are at least approaching the level of Dr. Strange's; she's shown tracking down and resolving major magickal problems on her own.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the comics, I would've said they're possibly equal.

But, since the film 'Thor: Ragnarok', I'd say Doctor Strange is the most powerful.

EDIT: Of course, where magical entities/humans are concerned, the DC universe is superior, with hugely powerful entities such The Spectre and Doctor Fate etc.

Comment: Well, the Marvel universe also has its share of hugely powerful entities like the Beyonder and Molecule Man (see the old and new "Secret Wars" stories, respectively. There are also cosmic entities like Eternity and The in-Betweener.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen Yes, you're right, my friend. I didn't think my statement through thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Doctor Strange since he had training and a cape to assist him as well. In Infinity War he stopped a black hole and can’t travel realms. Also he knows how to use the time stone, the only Avenger who knows how to use an infinity stone; and on top of that he’s stopped Dormammu and can travel through portals anywhere. If scarlet had training, she would almost equal him in power level, but for now I’m going with Doctor Strange, who can also multiply himself.

Comment: When did Doctor Strange stop a black hole?